# AWS, serverless SAM template - publishing nested applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have defined AWS Serverless nested applications within my root SAM template by using Location property pointing to my local file system (as advised [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-template-nested-applications.html) - Defining a Nested Application from the Local File System).
Packaging and deploying work perfectly fine - applications run on AWS just fine - everything works just fine, except publish.

I can not find a way to publish to the Serverless Application Repository my root application that would also (somehow) contain all nested applications (inside?).

```
sam publish \
    --template packaged.yaml \
    --region us-east-1
```

returns

```
Error: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: XX. Errors: Resource with id [YYYYYYYYYYY] is invalid. Location property must be an Application Location Object referencing a valid AWS Serverless Application Repository application.
```

All my Location properties after the packaging is done are something like:

```
https://s3.eu-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-storage/34ct54v6547b56756n7.template
```

Does it mean I still need to package or/and publish all of the nested applications first to have CodeUri properties defined as AWS s3 URLS and then somehow change their Locations references in the root packaged template?
Did anyone try that, maybe?